# How can I use wget to get files recursively if the username contains an @?

Tags: wget

Firstly my main goal is to try and get FTP files recursively in Centos.  However the actual FTP login contains an @ which ruins the syntax.  Is there some way to place the username in "double quotes" or some such equivalent such that I can use @in the username?

Comment: are you running ftp via command line?

Answer (score 1):

If you use wget's `--user=wh@tever` and `--password=bl@h` options rather than the `user:pass@host` syntax, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the @ by

```
&#64;
```

?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...you mean something like (assuming login of me@domain.com)

wget -r ftp://me&#64;domain.com:password@ftp.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

what about replacing `@` with `%40`

since it is posted by http special chars should be urlencoded.